# Resource Calendars in Microsoft Project 2003

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2003

I have developers in Quebec and in Ontario, and each province has different holidays.  In MS Project 2003, I selected Tools/Working Time and created two calendars called Ontario and Quebec and filled out the holidays appropriate for each.  In my resource sheet, I made the base calendar for each developer match their province.

With that in place, I created a task for a Quebec developer that takes 9 days and scheduled it as Must Start On Monday June 18th.  There is a holiday in the Quebec calendar for June 25th, so I assumed that the end date would come out as Friday, June 29th, but it shows up as Thursday.  MS Project seems to ignore the resource calendar when scheduling this task.

Shouldn't MS Project notice that the specified resource is not available on June 25th in this case?  Or have I misunderstood how the resource calendar works?

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: It is my understanding that Microsoft Products are only "Microsoft Certified" for 8 years.  Any usage outside of that period is a chancy operation and any dates generated should be viewed as purely speculative.

Comment: To be honest, I just need to get things done, and from that point of view MS Project 2003 is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the 'Task Type' is set to 'Fixed Duration' (see Task information -> advanced), the duration will not change, even if there is a holiday planned.

Check out the Resource usage view, and you will see that the resource is not scheduled on the holiday.

With task type equal to "Fixed units" or "Fixed Work", the duration should indeed take an extra day.

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot to consider the Task type field I guess - that makes good sense.